# When overriding Bootstrap is possible or not?

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4

I'm finding very random when I can or cannot override Bootstrap classe/ id with a custom .css

For example, to change default navbar-dark, Background and font-style overriding is acceptable. 
But font colour and size cannot change unless I force a change applying "style" inside of  element or as an "id" linked to an external css file.

What does not works:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark"style="background: red; color: 
yellow; font-family: cursive font-size: 50px;">
  <a href="" class="navbar-brand" style="color: yellow; font-size: 
 50px;">PATTERN</a>
</nav
```

Applying style on element works, such as:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark"style="background: red; font-family: 
cursive;">
  <a href="" class="navbar-brand" style="color: yellow; font-size: 
 50px;">PATTERN</a>
</nav
```

Being able only to use id inside of each element becomes a problem when I have a big navbar and I want to apply a class to all of them.

What can I do to customize or how can I learn about those limitations?

Thank you :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ There's a semi-colon missing in your inline styling _ `style="background: red; color: 
yellow; font-family: cursive font-size: 50px;">` should be `style="background: red; color: 
yellow; font-family: cursive; font-size: 50px;">`

Comment: You need to inspect the element to see what level of specificity is applied to the style you are trying to override and then match it - inline styles will mostly override as they are the highest level apart from important.  In your case the nav brand is styled by `.navbar-dark .navbar-brand` so as long as you match that specificity in your selector, it will be overriden - have a [read of this to understand specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends if the color style is set in Bootstrap on parent element and then it descends or it is set directly on child... And it is set on the child... so you need to set it directly on that child.

But use CSS, or LESS, SASS etc.. dont use inline classes, set it globaly for all children you want to target.

Like that:

```
.navbar-dark .navbar-brand {
    color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Hi Every! Thank you so much for your answer! It doesn't work for me though. It still doesn't override it.

Comment: @discombobulateme and do you load your CSS after bootstrap CSS? :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is directly related to CSS Specifity. CSS specifity applies when *there are two or more conflicting CSS rules that point to the same element*.
The specifity of the CSS rules determines which one of the conflicting rules will aply to your html element. In general, more specific CSS rules go over less specific ones. This is, from more specific to less specific:

1. **Inline styles**: styles defined in the "stype" attribute, inside the html tag.
2. **ID**: a CSS rule that references an element by its id instead of a class (for example #navbar).
3. **Classes, attributes and pseudo-classes**: most common css rules. In example:

```
.blueBackgroundClass {
   background: blue;
}
```

4. **Elements and pseudo-elements**: usually only used to make site-generic styles, such as:

```
p {
   font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

a {
   color: blue;
}
```

For more information about it I strongly recommend you to see the [CSS Specifity](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp) documentation.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer :) I do understand the conflict, I don't know how to solve it in Bootstrap, as it is an encapsulated wireframe

Comment: Probably inline styling is your best approach. You probably won't be able to modify the html tags as they come from, but you may find the way to do so by modifying them via javascript.